# Show that the set $U_{77,76}$ of solutions to $x^{76} = 1$ is a subgroup of $U_{77}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the set $U_{77,76}$ of solutions to $x^{76} = 1$ is a subgroup of $U_{77}$.

I don't understand this question at all but could someone also explain what it means by $U_{77}(76)$.

Comment: No no no, not U_{77,76}. It is U_77(76)

Comment: It seems to mean $U_{77}(76) = \{x \in U_{77} : x^{76} = 1\}$

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that was another form of writing it

Comment: But I still don't see why that would mean it is a subgroup.

Comment: Can I suggest that you think about it for a bit and then edit your question to say what you've tried? Do you know how to show something is a subgroup?

Comment: Do you know how to check that a subset is a subgroup? Do you know what it *means* for a subset to be a subgroup? All you do is have to check, really. For any abelian group $G$ and any natural $n$, the solutions to $x^n=e$ form a subgroup, as can be easily verified.

Comment: The set of elements with order dividing a fixed number always form a subgroup in communatist group.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, it looks like $U_{77}(76)$ is just the set of $x \in U_{77}$ such that $x^{76} = 1$.

Pick $a$ and $b$ such that $a^{76} = 1$ and $b^{76} = 1$. What can you say about the product $ab$? Etc.

Remember that a subgroup of a group $G$ is a subset that forms a group under the given operation. Verify the group axioms for the set in question to show that it's a subgroup.

Comment: How would I verify the group of axioms? What would they be?

Comment: Have you learned what a group is? The "group axioms" are the list of properties that define a group. So, for example, you need to show that your set is closed under the given operation (which looks like multiplication in this case). This means that if $a$ and $b$ are in your set, you need to show that $ab$ is as well. You also want to show that there's an identity element $1$, that multiplication is associative, and that every element $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1} = 1$. Note that you don't actually need to verify all of these to prove that a set is a subgroup of a given group.